# PL/SQL Joining tables inside of an iteration

Tags: loops, join, plsql, iteration

I'm just trying to self learn PL/SQL procedures over the last week and have run into a few beginner questions around understanding how loops/cursors work with joins in combination.

Any light that someone could shed would be great, as I am quite new to some of the concepts of PL/SQL around cursors.

Apologies in advance for the highly obscure example

In the example below, I am basically starting with table A and trying to obtain the name for the customer and then set a reason_code flag by: a) checking for join success on Table B, if join fails then checking if the customer is in area B (using Table C). In the hypothetical example below, I have also tried to create an output which contains data from another table (Customer Name).

I attempted to make the joins using a similar method to below:

> DECLARE
>
> order_cnt integer;
>
> cursor base1 is
>   select customer_id, subscription, reasoncode
>   from customersubscription
>
> BEGIN
>
> for base_rec in base1 loop
>
> select count(*)
>
> into order_cnt
>
> from customersubscription base, customerorder order
>
> where base.customer_id =  order.customer_id;
>
> if order_cnt > 1 then
>
> update customersubscription set reasoncode = 'Has ordered product'
>
> where current of base_rec;
>
> else...
>
> END LOOP
>
> END;

*As you can see, I have attempted to open a cursor for the base table and iterate through each record, joining to other tables to set a flag. This did not work, I assume its the way i've tried to join as it does not specify the current row. I have also not been able to find any examples of joining for data retrieval in the way I am attempting to derive the customer name*

Table A: CustomerSubscription

```
Customer_ID | SubscriptionID | reasoncode
123         | 567            |
124         |                |
```

Table B: CustomerOrder

```
Customer_ID | Order_ID | Product
123         | 567      | TITANIC
```

Table C: Customer

```
Customer_ID | Name    | Area     
123         | Roger   | E     
124         | Timothy | B
```

Output: Table A

```
Customer_ID | Name    | ReasonCode     
123         | Roger   | Has ordered Product    
124         | Timothy | Outside of area
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Select c.Customer_ID 
    ,c.Name
    ,Case When co.Order_id is not null 
            Then 'Has ordered Product'
          When Area ='B'
            Then 'Outside of area'
          Else 'UnKnown'
     End as ReasonCode
 from Customer as c
left join CustomerOrder as co on c.Customer_ID =co.Customer_ID
```

If you have multiple entries in CustomerOrder table for each Customer then query needs to be changed, as follows,

```
Select c.Customer_ID 
    ,c.Name
    ,Case When exists(Select COUNT(co.Order_ID) from CustomerOrder as co where c.Customer_ID =co.Customer_ID) 
         Then 'Has ordered Product'
          When Area ='B'
            Then 'Outside of area'
          Else 'UnKnown'
     End as ReasonCode
 from Customer as c
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but I am actually specifically looking to solve this problem using iteration and update a table with the results

Comment: @user3484575, If iteration then try to do it with while loop.

Comment: Thanks for that, would you be able to provide an example of how to actually make the join for each record within the loop?. I am fundamentally having difficulty understanding how syntactically make each record join to another table to retrieve/ check for the existence of a value. Appreciate any light you could shed on this

Comment: Surely, give me some time

Comment: In the example above it was reason_code, but i really just put that example there for illustrative purposes. I am really just trying to learn concepts around explicit cursors and iteration. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!